# Can't exclude directory in documentation coverage [compodoc]

Tags: angular, compodoc

I generate documentation with compodoc, I would like to exclude some files/directories from the documentation coverage

I added the exclude property of tsconfig.json file.

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "*.spec.ts",
    "./app/core-module/test"
  ]
```

The files are well excluded from the documentation but not from the documentation coverage.

Does anyone have any ideas please ?

Answer (score 3):

hi try to add separate tsconfig.compodoc.json

```
 {
        "include": [
            "src/**/*"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "node_modules/",
          "projects/"
        ]
      }
```